# CSS Form Layout funny

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem. I have a ASP.Net MVC 3 site, containing a user registration page with the following markup:

```
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Information</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            First Name
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("Firstname")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Last Name
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("Lastname")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Employee Number
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("EmployeeNo")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Id Number
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("Idnumber")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Date of birth
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("Dob")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Cell Number
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("CellNumber")
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Site Preferences</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Username
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("Username")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Password
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Password("Password")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Confirm Password
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Password("Confirm")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            E-mail
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBox("Email")
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Everything looks fine and their alignment is 100% except for the Id Number and E-mail text inputs which looks like its right aligned. The css is use looks like:

```
   form
   {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }
   fieldset
   {
       margin: 1em 0;
       border: none;
       border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
   }
   legend
   {
       margin: 1em 0;
       padding: 0 .5em;
       color: #036;
       background: transparent;
       font-size: 1.3em;
       font-weight: bold;
   }
   label, .editor-label
   {
       float: left;
       width: 100px;
       padding: 0 1em;
       text-align: right;
   }
   fieldset div
   {
       margin-bottom: .5em;
       padding: 0;
       display: block;
   }
   fieldset div input, fieldset div textarea
   {
       width: 150px;
       border-top: 1px solid #555;
       border-left: 1px solid #555;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
       border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
       padding: 1px;
       color: #333;
   }
   fieldset div select
   {
       padding: 1px;
   }
   div.fm-multi div
   {
       margin: 5px 0;
   }
   div.fm-multi input
   {
       width: 1em;
   }
   div.fm-multi label
   {
       display: block;
       width: 200px;
       padding-left: 5em;
       text-align: left;
   }
   #fm-submit
   {
       clear: both;
       padding-top: 1em;
       text-align: center;
   }
   #fm-submit input
   {
       border: 1px solid #333;
       padding: 2px 1em;
       background: #555;
       color: #fff;
       font-size: 100%;
   }
   input:focus, textarea:focus
   {
       background: #efefef;
       color: #000;
   }
   fieldset div.fm-req
   {
       font-weight: bold;
   }
   fieldset div.fm-req label:before
   {
       content: "* ";
   }

   #container
   {
       margin: 0 auto;
       padding: 1em;
       width: 350px;
       text-align: left;
   }
   p#fm-intro
   {
       margin: 0;
   }
```

What am I missing, why is it just the two fields thats all wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The width of the div with class .editor-label is not large enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the div with class .editor-label is not large enough.  Currently it is set to 100px.  But if you expand that to fit the full contents of `Confirm Password` then it should align itself.

Below is a demo of your code with a .editor-label width set to 200px.

http://jsfiddle.net/LuBUb/

Comment: @Pieterv ... Your welcome...dont forget to participate and select a correct answer.